# Sql Query update table1 by values of table2

Tags: sql

I have two tables named Workers and Stats

In the Workers table are a big first and last names list put into one column (stupidly) in a structure similar to this:

```
NameID,   Name
  1,      John
  2,      Smith
  3,      McDonald
  4,      Harry
```

In the Stats table are all the Statistics of workers, something like this:

```
id, firstnameid, secondnameid,  wage,    sold
 1,    4,           3,          1000,    10
 2,    1,           2,          2000,    20
```

Because this is so inconvenient I am trying to make up a query or something which will change the Stats table nameids to the actual names, something like:

```
UPDATE `Stats` SET `Stats.firstnameid` =  `Workers.Names` 
WHERE `Stats.firstnameid` = `Workers.NameID`
```

and then do the same for the secondnameid

So the outcome if this worked would be that the Stats table would be changed to look like this (using the example tables I have shown above):

```
 id,  firstnameid, secondnameid,       wage,    sold
 1,    Harry,      McDonald,          1000,     10
 2,    John,       Smith,             2000,    20
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks.

Comment: Your query seems working just as you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it!

Create a view instead:

```
create view v_stats as
    select s.id, fname.name as firstname, lname.name as lastname, s.wage, s.sold
    from stats s left outer join
         workers fname
         on s.firstnameid = fname.nameid left outer join
         workers lname
         on s.lastnameid = lname.nameid;
```

I have no idea why someone would design a database, splitting up the names like that.  Ok, that seems like bad database design or whatever.  You don't make it any better by compounding the problem by copying the names over.  Presumably, that table is maintained somehow.

If two employees have the same first name, do they have one row or two in the workers table?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear, there would be two rows, the workers table is just a names list.

Comment: @user1626410 . . . All the more reason you should use a view.  If a name changes, it will change in the `workers` table.  You don't want to copy the name around, where it might get out of date.  And you don't want to change the code for creating a new worker.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to change your table structure.  As for as moving the data, something like the below.

```
UPDATE
    Stats
SET
    s.firstName = w1.name,
    s.secondName= w2.name
FROM Stats AS s
INNER JOIN Workers AS w1 ON s.firstnameid = w1.NameID
INNER JOIN Workers AS w2 ON s.secondnameid= w2.NameID
```

I do like the idea of a workers table, but your workers table is really a name table which is very strange.  I would want a workers table which had columns firstname, lastname, address, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, when running this I get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Stats INNER JOIN Workers AS Workers1 INNER JOIN Workers AS' at line 6

Comment: @user1626410. Sorry, I wasn't thinking right.  See edited query.

Comment: I got it working by editing your first query, similar to this one. Thanks for the help!